# Sum of multiplication of all combination of m element from an array of n elements

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

Suppose I have an array `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and `m = 3`.
I need to find:

```
1*2*3 + 1*2*4 + 1*3*4 + 2*3*4
```

i.e Sum of multiplication of all combination of m element from an array of n elements.

One of the solution possible is to find all combination and then solving it but that would be `O(nCm)` solution. Is there any faster solution?

Comment: Would a lower bound be enough.  What is the application?.  The lower bound is $(m \times a1 \times a2 \times a3 \times\cdots an)$. Otherwise, it is pretty complicated

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is the value of the [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_m$ with as arguments the elements $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of your array. The traditional occurrence of these symmetric polynomials is the coefficient of $X^{n-m}$ the polynomial $(X+a_1)(X+a_2)\ldots(X+a_n)$ with roots $-a_1,-a_2,\ldots,-a_n$. You can make it a bit nicer by moving the $X$ to the other term: the coefficient of $X^n$ in the product $(1+a_1X)(1+a_2X)\ldots(1+a_nX)$ is also $e_m[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$.

The number of algebraic operations needed to compute this polynomial product is $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the generating-function view of the world, your sum is the coefficient of $x^m$ in $(1+1x)(1+2x)(1+3x)\dots(1+nx)$. I suspect this will lead to a fairly concrete form for the sum. In any case, it is quicker to calculate than all the $m$-subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: What is the faster way to find the sum of all the coefficients upto x^m?

ie - `coeff of x0` + `coeff of x1` + `coeff of x2` + ...`coeff of xm`?