# Generalize partial sum of a multivariate generating sequence

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

PLEASE CHECK EDIT $2$. It best explains my problem.

I know this question may be dumb but I have been working on it for over a day now and I can't seem to find any lead. So the question goes as follows:

We know that 1 + ${ x }_{ 1 }$ + ${ x }_{ 2 }$ + ${ x }_{ 3 }$ + ${ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 2 }$ + ${ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 3 }$ + ${ x }_{ 2 }{ x }_{ 3 }$ + ${ x }_{ 1 }{ x }_{ 2 }{ x }_{ 3 }$ = $\left( { 1+x }_{ 1 } \right) \left( { 1+x }_{ 2 } \right) \left( { 1+x }_{ 3 } \right) $. This can also be generalized for $x_n$. But I am looking for a formula that would give me only the sum of terms whose degree is atmost $k$. What I mean by degree in this context is, $x_1x_2x_3...x_6$ has a degree $6$. So, is it possible to generalize sum of that partial sequence? I looked up at many generating function articles but couldn't find anything. Please help me.

EDIT 1- More Clarification:

Let's say the sequence is

$1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_1x_4 + x_2x_3 + x_2x_4 + x_3x_4 + x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_3x_4 + x_1x_2x_3x_4$

Now, its sum is $(1 + x_1)(1 + x_2)(1 + x_3)(1 + x_4)$.

If $k=2$, I want to find the sum of only those terms, whose degree is atmost $2$: The terms with degree less than or equal to $2$ are:

$1 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_3 + x_1x_4 + x_2x_3 + x_2x_4 + x_3x_4$

So, is it possible to generalize this for some $k$?

EDIT 2: The best representation of my problem. Thanks to [mvxxx](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/698145/mvxxx)

If
$F(S,t)=[t^k](1+a_1t)(1+a_2t)(1+a_3t)⋯(1+a_nt)$

for example:

$F({a,b,c},2)=$

$[t^2](1+at)(1+bt)(1+ct)=$

$[t^2](abct^3+t^2(ab+ac+bc)+t(a+b+c)+1)=$

$ab+ac+bc$

And
$G(S,k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}F(S,i)$

I am looking for solving $G(S,k)$ in $O(k\ logk)$ or better.

Comment: You mean this? $\prod _{i=1}^k(1+x_i)$? When $k=3$ you get your example

Comment: I have edited the problem statement. Please take a look.

Comment: Are you looking for notation for the elementary symmetric polynomials?

Comment: I am pretty sure that no nice formula exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how closed formula are you looking for. In my opinion there is no "real" (without spoofing) closed formula but we can write something similar in use of [my old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332936/698145).
So let say that
$$F(S,t) = [t^k](1+a_1 t)(1+a_2 t)(1+a_3 t) \cdots (1+a_n t) $$

for example:

$$F(\left\{a,b,c \right\},2) = \\  [t^2](1+a t)(1+b t)(1+c t) = \\ [t^2] \left(a b c t^3+t^2 (a b+a c+b c)+t (a+b+c)+1 \right) = \\ a b+a c+b c $$

Then what are you looking for is
$$G(S, k) = \sum_{i=0}^k F(S,i)  $$

### Draft of solution in wolfram language

```
T[x_] := your_polynomial
M[x_] := Collect[T[x],x]
G[x_] := Sum[Coefficient[M[x],i],{i,0,k}]
```

references: 
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html

Comment: $F\left( \left\{ a,b,c \right\} ,2 \right) = ab +bc+ ac$. 

We had to pairwise multiply them all and add them. Is there a better way to find it, for all $0$ to $k$? Because if $k$ goes higher and higher, then adding all $k$-wise products will be very computationally expensive. Basically, is possible to compute $F(S,i)$ in constant time or at most in $O(log n)$?

Comment: I am not sure about existing such algorithm. I gave only mathematical proposal how to do that

Comment: I really appreciate your help. You have better explained my problem. I am looking for solving $G(S,k)$ in $O(k\ logk)$ or better.

Comment: I am glad that my approach helps you. If I comes to solution in $O(k\ logk)$ , I will update post

Comment: It is worth to see that we need to collect only once polynomial. I added draft in `wolfram`

Comment: Interesting. That will help. I will mark this as accepted.